# Unchecking checkboxes programmatically

Tags: c#, checkbox, devexpress, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a certain requirement that, if the first checkbox in a row of checkboxes is unchecked, then all the other checkboxes must be unchecked.
Here is a sample
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqlav.png)

I am using DevExpress 21.2.3 and `RepositoryItemCheckEdit` as the check box

Can anyone help me to achieve this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of check boxes. Then If checkBox1 is equal to false(unchecked), set the check boxes in list to false.

```
if( checkBox1.Checked== false ) 
{
  for(int i = 0; i <= checkBoxes.Count; i++) 
  {
    checkBoxes[i].Checked = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply like this:

- firstly, create a few checkboxes in your program:
  [image]
- secondly, declare a CheckBox array in the class and, in the Load() method, initialize all checkboxes to created CheckBox array:
  [image]
- finally, in the CheckedChanged() method, write code which will check or uncheck all checkboxes, depending on the first checkbox.
  [image]